# Correct way to std::sort a std::vector of N-Dimensional floating points

Tags: c++, sorting

I want to `std::sort` a vector full of three dimensional points in a way that each point is primarily aligned based on the z value, secondarily by y value, and at last by the x value.

A desired output example could be

```
192 1 1
200 1 1
208 1 2
-296 2 2
-288 2 3
```

However, my approach to `std::sort` seems to be not very nice. On the one hand there is an `==` on a float. On the other hand my functor is rather complicated. Additionally, this approach sucks if I have a N-dimensional point. Is there a better way?

Example code:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>

struct point {
  float x;
  float y;
  float z;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<point> foo = {
        { 1 ,  72 , 10 },
        { 2 ,  72 , 9 },
        { 3 ,  72 , 8 },
        { 32 ,  71 , 7 },
        { 4 ,  70 , -152 },
        { 32 ,  72 , -144 },
        { 5 ,  72 , -136 },
        { 5 ,  72 , -128 },
        { 5 ,  72 , -120 },
        { 32 ,  72 , -112 },
        { 32 ,  72 , -104 },
        { 32 ,  72 , -96 },
        { 32 ,  72 , -88 },
        { 32 ,  3 , -80 }
    };

  std::sort(
    foo.begin(),
    foo.end(),
    [](const point &a, const point &b) {
    if (a.z < b.z) return true;
    if (a.z == b.z && a.y < b.y) return true;
    if (a.z == b.z && a.y == b.y && a.x < b.x) return true;
    return false;
    }
  );

  for(auto p : foo) {
      printf("%f,%f,%f\n", p.x, p.y, p.z);
  }
}
```

Comment: well the vector is only one dimensional

Comment: The core point is to use `std::tie` for comparing multiple elements.

Comment: thanks for the tip. I'll try that out

Comment: `[](const point &lhs, const point &rhs) { return std::tie(lhs.z, lhs.y, lhs.x) < std::tie(rhs.z, rhs.y, rhs.x); }`.

Comment: Your comparison does what std::tie would do. If you think that the float eqaulity test is a problem, std::tie would not help.

Comment: Why not add op<() on point?